# Can I use OrderBy<T> to order by a Join<T> entity?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

I need to translate a Linq query into Dynamic Linq but I'm having a problem with the OrderBy part.

This is the Linq query:

```
var q = from pp in ctx.MyEntity
        join c in sortedListString on pp.CountryId.ToString() equals c.Substring(9)
        orderby c ascending
        select pp;
```

As you can see, I'm sorting by the entinty in the join.
Now I need to write the same query but with dynamic linq and I have:

```
var q = from pp in ctx.MyEntity
        select pp;

q = q.Join(
    sortedListString, 
    o => o.CountryId.ToString(), 
    i => i.Substring(9), (o, i) => o
).OrderBy(???);
```

What should I put in the OrderBy, knowing that I want to order by `sortedListString`?

Comment: dont see no `sortedListString`

Comment: You're returning `o` only, so there's nothing left from `sortedListString` to order by.

Comment: I personally prefer using the LINQ declarative query syntax because it is much more simpler and easier to read

Comment: sortedListString is just a List<String>. This is a kind of tricky, not so clean hack I'm doing here so bare with me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "dynamic linq" here, but equivalent of your query using "full" LINQ syntax is:

```
var q = ctx.MyEntity
    .Join(sortedListString, 
        pp => pp.CountryId.ToString(), 
        c => c.Substring(9), 
        (pp, c) => new { pp, c })
    .OrderBy(t => t.c)
    .Select(t => t.pp);
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to convert "query syntax" to "method syntax" in LINQ: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/query-syntax-and-method-syntax-in-linq

Comment: @kimbaudi yes, that's what I meant. I was lacking that naming in my vocabulary :)